# Perfino java process IOwait consuming "APPARENT DEADLOCK!!!"

Tags: java, deadlock, perfino, iowait

we reboot process java perfino every night, after reboot it starts consuming 24-30% IOWait and the software doesn't work until 30-40 minutes...

The output when it is starting is:

```
2022-09-05 09:09:53,390 INFO  [main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 120000, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> perfino, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.h2.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> z8kfltar3gp7qzmlngbl|3e2055d6, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 210, initialPoolSize -> 5, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:h2:file:/var/opt/perfino/db/perfino;LOCK_TIMEOUT=30000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MAX_COMPACT_TIME=5000, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 21600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 180, maxPoolSize -> 80, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2022-09-05 09:13:43,385 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfltar3gp7qzmlngbl|3e2055d6, dataSourceName->perfino]-AdminTaskTimer] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@fcdef27 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2022-09-05 09:13:43,389 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfltar3gp7qzmlngbl|3e2055d6, dataSourceName->perfino]-AdminTaskTimer] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@fcdef27 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks:
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@40370a95
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfltar3gp7qzmlngbl|3e2055d6, dataSourceName->perfino]-HelperThread-#1
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@20636163
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfltar3gp7qzmlngbl|3e2055d6, dataSourceName->perfino]-HelperThread-#2
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@713d0ab1
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfltar3gp7qzmlngbl|3e2055d6, dataSourceName->perfino]-HelperThread-#0
    Pending Tasks:
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@58833ffd
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfltar3gp7qzmlngbl|3e2055d6, dataSourceName->perfino]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
        org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:191)
        org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.getTransactionIsolation(JdbcConnection.java:784)
        org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.isValid(JdbcConnection.java:1654)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester$2.activeCheckConnectionNoQuery(DefaultConnectionTester.java:136)
```

kind regards,

Comment: During the startup phase, create the file `<perfino data directory>/sample_server` then after 3 minutes a .jps file is created in the directory `<perfino data directory>/profile`. Please send that file to support@ej-technologies.com.